# codeigniter pagination: links are working but the records are repeated on other pages

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

Can anyone please help me? I am trying to paginate my table. all links are working, but the items are repeated on other pages. I tried similar questions on here, but nothing is working.

```
function index($type="deposit", $limit_from=0)
{
    $limit_from = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
    $total_records = $this->Expense->get_total_rows($type);
    $data['controller_name'] = $this->get_controller_name();

    $lines_per_page = 3; 
    $data[$type.'s'] = $this->Expense->get_records($lines_per_page, $limit_from, $type);

    $config['base_url'] = base_url('index.php/expenses/index/'.$type);
    $config['total_rows'] = $total_records;
    $config['per_page'] = 3;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
    // $choice = $total_records / $config['per_page'];
    // $config['num_links'] = round($choice);
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['first_url'] = base_url('index.php/expenses/index/'.$type.'/1');

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view('expenses/'.$type, $data);
    $this->_remove_duplicate_cookies();
}
```

Comment: Hello,

Please refer this link maybe you will get help!

https://www.formget.com/pagination-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. I got it to work: below is what I finally did and it is working great!

```
function index($type="deposit", $sort_by='deposit_date', $sort_order='asc', $page_limit=0)

{
    $data['controller_name'] = $this->get_controller_name();
    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = site_url("expenses/index/$type/$sort_by/$sort_order");
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Expense->get_total_rows($type);
    $config['per_page'] = 4;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 6;

    $data['num_rows'] = $config['total_rows'];
    $data['type'] = $type;


    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(6)) ? $this->uri->segment(6) : 0;

    $data[$type.'s'] = $this->Expense->get_records($config["per_page"], $page, $type, $sort_by, $sort_order);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['headers'] = $this->Expense->table_headers($type);
    $data['sort_by'] = $sort_by;
    $data['sort_order'] = $sort_order;


    $this->load->view('expenses/'.$type, $data);
    $this->_remove_duplicate_cookies();
}
```